# Proving a Gamma function type integral is an entire functiin

Tags: integration

I am trying to prove that $\int_1^{\infty} u^{z-1}e^{-u}du $ is an entire function. I m trying to show that the integrand is less than $Ce^{-u} $ for every z but it’s turning out to be harder than I imagined.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Such an inequality with $C$ independent of $z$ does not hold. But you do not need it to prove the integral is well defined. Since $u\ge1$ is real, we have
$$
\bigl|u^{z-1}\bigr|=\frac1u\,|e^{(\log u)z\le}\bigr|\le e^{(\log u)\Re z}.
$$
This shows that the integral is well defined for all $z\in\Bbb C$, and the usual arguments show that it defines an entire function.